# Nested SQL Server transaction performing cascade delete

Tags: sql-server, transactions, nested, cascade

Suppose I have a table called Companies that has a DepartmentID column. There's also a Departaments table that has as EmployeeID column. Of course I have an Employee table as well. The problem is that I want to delete a company, so first i have to delete all the employees for every departament and then all the departaments in the company.
Cascade Delete is not an option, therefore i wish to use nested transactions. I'm new to SQL so I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need nested transactions here.  You only need one actual transaction:

```
BEGIN TRAN

DELETE FROM Employee
    FROM Employee
    INNER JOIN Department ON Employee.DepartmentID = Department.DepartmentID
    INNER JOIN Company ON Department.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
    WHERE Company.CompanyID = @CompanyID

DELETE FROM Department
    FROM Department
    INNER JOIN Company ON Department.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
    WHERE Company.CompanyID = @CompanyID

DELETE FROM Company
    WHERE Company.CompanyID = @CompanyID

COMMIT TRAN
```

Note the double FROM, that is not a typo, it's the correct SQL syntax for performing a JOIN in a DELETE.

Each statement is atomic, either the entire DELETE will succeed or fail, which isn't that important in this case because the entire batch will either succeed or fail.

BTW- I think you had your relationships backwards.  The Department would not have an EmployeeID, the Employee would have a DepartmentID.

Comment: Your queries can be optimized to remove the INNER JOINs on Company. Or would this be something SQL Server would do automatically?

Comment: You're right. I just added them to be explicit, but you could change your WHERE clause to:

WHERE Department.CompanyID = @CompanyID

Answer (score 0):

I'm not answering your question, but foreign Keys *is* the way to go, why is it not an option?

As for nested transactions they are:

```
BEGIN
  delete from Employee where departmentId = 1;
  BEGIN
     delete from Department where companyId = 2;
     BEGIN
        delete from Company where companyId = 2;
     END
  END
END
```

Programmatically it looks different of course, but that'd depend on the platform you are using